# Creating hyperlinked text that returns the text clicked as input inside the app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working with a Shiny project in which I would like to take text rendered inside the Shiny app and make each word in that text a hyperlink that when clicked sends the clicked text as an input to another function inside the app.

Here is a toy example of what I'm working with so far which only attempts to get the hyperlinked words to trigger an `reactiveEvent` and render the text that was clicked. Say my rendered text is in `data`. I markup the text in `data` and output the results as HTML to `markup`. Ideally what would happen is when I click the hyperlinked word 'This', the `clicked_text` output would display the text 'This'.

The actionLink syntax I'm using for the markup has two problems: 1) only the first hyperlinked word triggers `input$clicked_text` and 2) the value of `input$clicked_text` is an integer registering how many times the hyperlink as been clicked.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
        htmlOutput("markup"),
        textOutput("clicked_text")
)

# sample data
data <- c("This", "is", "a", "sentence")

# function to markup text
markup.text <- function(data) {
        markup <- lapply(data, function(text) {
                paste0("<a id = 'clicked_text' href = '#' class = 'action-button shiny-bound-input' value = '",
                       text,
                       "'>",
                       text,
                       "</a>")
        }) %>%
                paste(collapse = " ")
        return(markup)
}

server <- function(input, output) {

        output$markup <- renderUI({ # display the marked-up text
                HTML(markup.text(data))
                })
        output$clicked_text <- eventReactive(input$clicked_text, { # display clicked text output
                input$clicked_text
        })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Your help and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think these revisions should do the trick:

1. Change the link tag structure to look like this:

`<a href='#' onclick='detect_click(this)'>text</a>`

2. Create a Javascript file in the same folder, called detect_click.js (could be named anything though). Put the following code in the file:

`function detect_click(el) {
  Shiny.onInputChange('clicked_text', el.innerHTML);
}`

3. Change the UI to read the Javascript file:

`ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("markup"),
  textOutput("clicked_text"),
  includeScript("detect_click.js")
)`

4. Now within the server, you can use input$clicked_text as if it were any ordinary Shiny input - create reactive objects and output as normal, and it'll change any time a link created with the tag structure above is clicked.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a million.